# Use Split, Join, and another function in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2014

I have a field in SQL Server that contains an comma separated list. Here are 2 examples:

```
select 'ex1,ex2,ex3' as str union all
select 'ax1,ax2'
```

In my report, I have to transform all of these values (5 in this case) using a function. In this question I will use Trim, but in actuality we are using another custom made function with the same scope.

I know how I can split every value from the string and recombine them:

```
=Join(Split(Fields!str.Value,","),", ")
```

This works great. However, I need to execute a function before I recombine the values. I thought that this would work:

```
=Join( Trim(Split(Fields!VRN.Value,",")) ,", ")
```

However, this just gives me an error:

> Value of type '1-dimensional array of String' cannot be converted to 'String'. (rsCompilerErrorInExpression)

I can't personally change the function that we use.

How do I use an extra function when dealing with both an split and a join?

Comment: The Trim function requires a single string as input, while Split output returns an array of strings which is invalid. Something similar is happening with your custom function

Comment: Is it possible in any way to use functions that require a single string as input to work on an array of strings, without actually writing custom code?

Comment: I think that's not possible since vb function inputs and outputs are specific

Comment: What exactly is the custom transform doing?

Comment: We store data in a way so that you can't just use a normal select statement to get the values. This function is needed to get the actual values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use custom code to include all the logic (Split->Custom Code->Join).

Make adjustments inside the loop to call your custom function instead of trim

```
Public Function fixString (ByVal s As String) As String

Dim  mystring() As String  

mystring = s.Split(",")

For index As Integer = 0 To mystring.Length-1
    mystring(index) = Trim(mystring(index))
Next 

Return Join(mystring, ",")

End Function
```

To call the custom code use the following expression

```
Code.fixString( Fields!VRN.Value )
```

Comment: I was hoping that I wouldn't need Custom Code because I feared it would become to complex, but your code is quite nice and compact! I just started writing my own Custom Code, but I'll just use yours instead. Thank you very much!